# apache poi - create a table at a bookmark

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to place a table at a bookmark in a word document using poi

the paragraph is found

```
 CTP ctp = paragraph.getCTP(); 
    // Get all bookmarks and loop through them 
    for( CTBookmark bookmark  in ctp.getBookmarkStartList())
    { 
    for(j = 0; j < viewScope.Bookmarks.length; j++)
        {
         if(bookmark.getName().equals(viewScope.Bookmarks[j]))
```

A table does get created but the word file is corrupt ... "word found unreadable content"

```
XmlCursor cursor = null;
 cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
          // cursor.toNextSibling();
  XWPFTable wTable = paragraph.getBody().insertNewTbl(cursor);
 
  XWPFTableRow row  = wTable.createRow();   //
                row.addNewTableCell();
                XWPFTableCell cell = row.createCell();
                cell.setText("New work");
            cursor.dispose();
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the nice world of `XWPFTable` creating methods. Instead of creating an empty table `apache poi` creates tables having rows and empty cells already. And what exactly it creates changes from version to version. So you cannot be sure what already exists and what not. So you always need to check. Is there a row already or needs one to create? Is there a cell already or needs one to create?

In your case:

```
...
  if (paragraph != null) {
   cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
   XWPFTable table = paragraph.getBody().insertNewTbl(cursor);
   XWPFTableRow row  = table.getRow(0); if (row == null) row = table.createRow();
   XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell(0); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell();
   cell.setText("New work");
   cursor.dispose(); 
  }
...
```

See [Inserting XWPFTable in between contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254987/inserting-xwpftable-in-between-contents/49261282#49261282) where I provided a code which inserts a table in between existing paragraphs dependent on the text contents. There I have edited now because `apache poi` formerly had put a paragraph already in a new created cell. But now it does that not more. So now you also have to check whether is there a paragraph already or needs to be created.