# Placeholder for XWPFTable

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

Is there way with apache xwpf libary to add new table to specific place inside doc where is placeholder?

```
`    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
      for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
        String text = run.getText(0);
        if (text != null) {
          for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() != null) {
              text = text.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
          }
          if (text.equals(placeholder)) {
              //i want to add table here
          } else {
            String[] lines = text.split("\n");
            if (lines.length > 1) {
              run.setText("", 0);
              run.setText(lines[0], 0);
              for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
                run.addBreak();
                run.setText(lines[i], i);

              }
            } else {
              run.setText(text, 0);
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
```

Its always add at end of docx when I create table.

Comment: Use [XWPFDocument.nsertNewTbl](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#insertNewTbl-org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor-). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254987/inserting-xwpftable-in-between-contents/49261282#49261282 for how to use.